# different sessions for www and non-www versions of app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, .htaccess, heroku, devise

The www and non-www versions of my Rails app are two completely different sessions, and I want to prevent www by redirecting to https.

[This](https://help.heroku.com/J2R1S4T8/can-heroku-force-an-application-to-use-ssl-tls) says to use `config.force_ssl = true` in `config/environments/production.rb` to force https, but this doesn't prevent www. Unless there's a better way and it involves sharing session info between www and non-www? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should redirect(301) your www to your non-www version. You will avoid duplication of content and you will stick to just one session.